# How to set environment variable in Solaris 11 for ant?

Tags: ant, environment-variables, solaris

I am trying to install ant in Solaris. I am using this:
https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

but I have no idea how to set the ANT_HOME environment variable. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the ANT_HOME temporally, typing `export ANT_HOME=you ant path` in your installing terminal. Otherwise, you can add ANT_HOME permanently by adding a line of `export ANT_HOME=you ant path` in /etc/profile file (you have to own root privilege).

Comment: I did that but then when I tried to run ant i got: Error: `Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher`

Comment: nevermind, i did it wrong. but i have a different problem now:
`Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed`

Comment: ok well i restarted and tried to reset set the ANT_HOME but it's not working anymore :(

Comment: Maybe you have to set two environment variables: ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME